# React Redux mapstatetoprops undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, store, mapstatetoprops

i'm working with react, redux and firestore
I'm trying to pass user to a component and then with uid pull some data from firestore.
but for unknown (to me) reason i always get undefined at first but on second render i get the correct data.

**App.js:**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: {},
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { setCurrentUser } = this.props;
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = await FB.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      console.log('User:', user);
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user });
        localStorage.setItem('user', user.uid);
      } else {
        this.setState({ user: null });
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
      }
      setCurrentUser(user);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className='App'>
          <Header />
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' exact element={<Page/>} />
          </Routes>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  currentUser: selectCurrentUser,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setCurrentUser: (user) => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**user action**

```
import { UserActionTypes } from "./user.types";

export const setCurrentUser = (user) => ({
  type: UserActionTypes.SET_CURRENT_USER,
  payload: user,
});
```

**user selecter:**

```
import { createSelector } from "reselect";

  const selectUser = (state) => state.user;

  export const selectCurrentUser = createSelector([selectUser],(user) => .currentUser
```

**page:**

```
const Page=({ currentUser }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  const userDB = async (currentUser) => {
  console.log('userDB START:', currentUser);
    if (!currentUser) return;
    const userUID = currentUser.currentUser.uid;
    const ref = doc(firestore, 'users', userUID);
    const data = await getDoc(ref);
    const dataSet = await data.json();

    if (data) {
//NOTE THAT I NEVER GET IN HERE
      console.log('docSnap.data: ', data.data());
      setUser(data.data());
    } else {
      console.log('No such document!');
    }
  };
 useEffect(() => {
userDB();
}, []);

return ();
};
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  currentUser: selectCurrentUser,
    });

   export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Page)
```

output is:

> userDB START: undefined

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: It's undefined because within `userDB`, `currentUser` is referring to the function argument, an argument than you never pass when calling `userDB()` within the useEffect.

Comment: The title is confusing, why do you assume mapStateToProps is undefined?

Comment: Are you sure you're using `createStructuredSelector` correctly? The docs say it "takes an object whose properties are input-selectors and returns a structured selector". However redux is calling mapStateToProps with the state object and expect it to return another object.

Comment: because of "console.log('userDB START:', currentUser);" which prints to console 'undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
  userDB(currentUser);
}, []);
```

In case mapStateToProps is actually undefined like your title says

```
<Route path='/' exact element={<Page currentUser={this.state.user} />} />
```

Comment: you are right, must have deleted it while experimenting. but still, at page loading i get undefined at currentUser which cause the problem

Comment: When you say it causes a problem, what problem does it cause exactly? Note that when doing ajax requests, on first render the user will always be undefined, because of how asynchronous operations work. Then after the promise has resolved and the state updated, another re-render is triggered and then you get the user.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
based on @timotgl, thank you!

**App.js:**
removed localstorage because it was not it use.

**page:**

```
const Page= ({ currentUser }) => {

 const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  const userDB = async (currentUser) => {
    if (!currentUser) return;
    const userUID = currentUser.uid;
    const ref = doc(firestore, 'users', userUID);
    const data = await getDoc(ref);
    const dataSet = await data;

    if (dataSet) {
      console.log('docSnap.data: ', dataSet.data());
      setUser(dataSet.data());
    } else {
      console.log('No such document!');
    }
  };
//changes in useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(userDB(currentUser));
  }, [currentUser]);

  return ();
};
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  currentUser: selectCurrentUser,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Page);
```